# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column * with api >=29

Tags: java, android, permissions

this is what written in logcat in android studio and which also causing crashing app when starts with android 29 and +.

My Logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column *
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:172) 
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142) 
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:472) 
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1183) 
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1115) 
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:1071)
```

I tried to add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in application in mainfest but still the problem,

its may becouse of this permission

```xml
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

with android 10. but I don't know how to solve.

Comment: This isn't [tag:crush] related.

Comment: But after updating sdk to 30, the app stoped working